# One to one rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model which has_one profile
and profile model which belongs_to user.
How can I make sure that once user makes a profile. That user cannot make another profile.

Comment: to totally make sure it never happens add a unique constraint on profiles for (id,user_id).  or check for uniqueness of user_id in your profile class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

Comment: BTW, if I were in your shoes, and if it were for MySQL or PostgreSQL backend, I would have also created a unique index on "profiles" table. The unique index would have been on the "user_id" column. Here is the migration:
`add_index :profiles, [:user_id], :unique => true`